# What does this paragraph try to convey?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Anxiety may be compared with dizziness. He whose eye happens to look down into the yawning abyss becomes dizzy. But what is the reason for this? It is just as much in his own eyes as in the abyss . . . Hence, anxiety is the dizziness of freedom.

From *The Concept of Anxiety* by Søren Kierkegaard.

Comment: I think the writer is trying to express something profound that might take the entire article or book to understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of [philosophy.se].

Comment: @CJDennis The problem is that if this question was posed on Philosophy.SE, the answer would not explain it in such a manner that it would be helpful to a non-native-speaker, and would end up confusing the asker more.

Comment: @Fivesideddice That doesn't make it on topic here. It might be that there is no suitable site for this question. It happens. We're actually not here to answer every question, just the good ones that haven't already been answered.